# Firefox 3.6 under debian squeeze

Tags: firefox, debian

While I want to start my Firefox 3.6 which I installed under /opt/firefox/

I have the Following Error:

```
[root@box]: ./firefox-bin 
./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is my ldd output:

```
ldd firefox-bin
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77cf000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf779e000)
        libxul.so => not found
        libxpcom.so => not found
        libmozalloc.so => not found
        libplds4.so => /usr/lib32/libplds4.so (0xf779a000)
        libplc4.so => /usr/lib32/libplc4.so (0xf7796000)
        llibnspr4.so => /usr/lib32/libnspr4.so (0xf7762000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf775d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7668000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7642000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7624000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf74dd000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d0000)
```

The file is there an all the others too:

```
[root@box]: locate libxul   
 /opt/firefox/libxul.so
```

So they are 3 files missing. Can you help to get me them?

EDIT:

With the short fix:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/firefox/
```

I get the same error with ./firefox-bin

```
./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start it with /opt/firefox/firefox

Comment: Then i have this problem: `[root@box]: ./firefox
./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have ia32-libs-gtk installed ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is something wrong with you package mananger ...

```
ldd firefox-bin
    libxul.so => not found
    ...
locate libxul
     /opt/firefox/libxul.so
```

this part can be solved with

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/firefox/
..../firefox-bin
```

or

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/firefox/ ..../firefox-bin
```

Comment: Ok, really nice now i become the same error with the firefox-bin. That there is no `./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: You should be able to fix it the same way, `locate lib...` then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...:...`, but take care of the lib versions, that's just a fix, to the way it's supposed to work!

Comment: I testet it with: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0:/opt/firefox/libxul.so But he still can't find libpangoft2

Comment: ok real nice i think i have now all of the .so files. But a new Error ;): libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: that's what I wanted to warn you about "take care of the lib versions", `ELFCLASS64` means you're using the X86_64b version of the lib instead of the i686, or vis-versa

Comment: I will try that ;) I've i found the other lib ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```